# Windows 10 Bluetooth pairing issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

So, to keep it short: Suddenly my Windows 10 Bluetooth won't pair anything. I've tried multiple devices and every time I hit the "Pair" button, a minute goes by and I get an error:

```
That didn't work
Try again, and make sure your Bluetooth headset is still discoverable.
```

or

```
That didn't work
Try again, and make sure your game controller is still discoverable.
```

Yeah, I'm trying to connect my PS4 DS4 controller to my Windows computer with Bluetooth. At first it worked like a charm, using the DS4Windows Software. The software installs an Virtual Bus Driver, which may be removed afterwards. That did not help me after my pairing problem occurred.

I suspect something is wrong with the Bluetooth Support Service, as it is this service responsible for the pairing part.

I've changed updated drivers, rolled back. Rolled back windows. Wiped drivers. Tried Generic Bluetooth drivers. Nothing.

Thing is, pairing worked a couple of days ago.

Any suggestions?

**Relevant specs:**

- MSI Z170A GAMING M9
- Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4 Bluetooth 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work in the end.

**Solution**: Probably something caused the Bluetooth module to get stuck in a "searching/pairing" loop of some kind, prohibiting me to pair any devices at all.

I disconnected the module from my motherboard. Booted up, shutdown, connected module again. Woila - it works properly.

If you are experiencing troubles getting your DS4 controllers to work via BT, lemme know - I'm pretty sure I could be at help :)