# Win10 Bluetooth connection issues: All BT devices pair, briefly connect and immediately disconnect

Tags: windows, bluetooth, dongle

the last few days I've been trying to fix an issue I am having with my bluetooth connection.

After trying everything google has to offer, I've gone so far as to buy both a new bluetooth dongle and re-installing Win10 (clean reset via cloud download), however the issue still persists.

[GIF of pairing a device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID9LR.gif)

Trying to reconnect to the device simply tells me:

```
That didn't work. Make sure your Bluetooth device is still discoverable, then try again.
```

Pairing and installation of any required drivers seems to work flawlessly for any of my BT devices.

Running the Bluetooth Troubleshooter finds and repairs the problem "Check Bluetooth radio status: Fixed", but it finds and "fixes" this issue even when running the troubleshooter again right after. The detailed view of the troubleshooter results does not give any further insight.

I found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1086535/windows-10-bluetooth-pairing-issue) of someone with a somewhat similar sounding issue, however his solution of unplugging the BT dongle and restarting the computer is something I have tried (and circumvented by trying a completely different bluetooth dongle on a fresh win10 install)

I am very grateful for any advice!

EDIT: I am able to send files to my PC via bluetooth, this seems to work without any issues.
EDIT2: I forgot to mention that the solutions from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1312011/windows-10-bluetooth-device-wont-connect-after-windows-reset?rq=1) unfortunately did not help either.